# How does getBoundingClientRect works after scale?

Tags: javascript

I have div block inside I make a click and draw a circle using this:

```
  let rect = this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
```

When I scale this block and click again I get wrong circle position.
How does getBoundingClientRect works after scale?

In code above e.clientX and e.clientY are static. Only rect is changed after scale

Comment: What does wrong mean here?  What is this "circle" you talk about? gBCR is relative to the viewport, so the values you get are the ones of the transformed element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.clientX` and `e.clientY` return the cursor position relative to the viewport, not relative to the element you are hovering.

You need to account for the element position as well as its scale factor:

```js
const rect = document.getElementById('rect');
const scaledRect = document.getElementById('scaledRect');

function updateCursorPosition(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  const coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Assuming the scaling is the same in both axis:
  const scale = target.getBoundingClientRect().width / target.offsetWidth;
  
  target.setAttribute('data-coords', JSON.stringify({
    x: (e.clientX - coords.left) / scale,
    y: (e.clientY - coords.top) / scale,
  }, null, 2));
}

rect.onmousemove = updateCursorPosition
scaledRect.onmousemove = updateCursorPosition;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#rect,
#scaledRect {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  background: cyan;
}

#scaledRect {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: yellow;
}

#rect::before,
#scaledRect::before {
  content: attr(data-coords);
}
```

```html
<pre id="rect"></pre>
<pre id="scaledRect"></pre>
```

Comment: I have a custom value: let scale = 1 and step 0.1. So, how to apply scale = 1.1 to container and recalculate point click?

I have tried this:

`click$.pipe(withLatestFrom(merge$, scale$)).subscribe((data: any) => {
      let [e, pointElement, scale] = data;
      let rect = this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = (e.clientX - rect.left) / scale;
      var y = (e.clientY - rect.top) / scale;
    });`

Comment: I have only one container that I can scale and rotate. Inside this container I can add a point by click. So when scale is default == 1 drawing click works fine, when I scale it has wrong position

Comment: I think it would be easier if you update your question with more details about the code you are currently using, but from what you say it looks like you first need to calculate the actual scale, so if `baseScale = 1` and `step = 0.1`, then `scale = baseScale + step`.